# Creating a JSON structure

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to define an initial JSON structure with a list and dictionaries. My code is as below:

```
import json

transactionSubmission = {}
documentDetails = []
documentDetails_dict = {}
generalDetails = {}
documentDetails_dict.update(generalDetails)
documentDetails.append(documentDetails_dict)
transactionSubmission.update({'documentDetails': [documentDetails]})
transactionSubmission_json = json.dumps(transactionSubmission)
print(transactionSubmission_json)
```

I am getting output as below:

```
{
  "documentDetails": [
    [
      {
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

But i am expecting an output as below:

```
{
  "documentDetails": [
    {
      "generalDetails": {}
    }
  ]
}
```

Appreciate any help on this please..

Comment: Your expectation isn't legal JSON.  The "generalDetails" key has no value.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will be appending Key: Value pairs to the generalDetails dictionary. To start with, i am defining the JSON structure first.

Comment: There is no need to do that. You can build the structure as you assign values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fixes what you are trying to do:

```
import json

transactionSubmission = {}
documentDetails = []
documentDetails_dict = {}
generalDetails = {}
documentDetails_dict['generalDetails'] = generalDetails
documentDetails.append(documentDetails_dict)
transactionSubmission['documentDetails'] = documentDetails
transactionSubmission_json = json.dumps(transactionSubmission)
print(transactionSubmission_json)
```

Output:

```
{"documentDetails": [{"generalDetails": {}}]}
```

But you can simplify things:

```
import json
transaction = {'documentDetails':[{'generalDetails':{}}]}
print(json.dumps(transaction))
print(json.dumps(transaction,indent=2)) # for readability
```

Output:

```
{"documentDetails": [{"generalDetails": {}}]}
{
  "documentDetails": [
    {
      "generalDetails": {}
    }
  ]
}
```